# Google Instant App - How to be go about automating with Appium

Tags: android, appium, android-instant-apps

We understand that the app needs to be launched by a browser and then a app container comes up with the cached app. However, we don't know how to move the handle from the browser the app container. Any thoughts?

Comment: Would this not be similar to switching from one app to another app? see https://discuss.appium.io/t/switch-between-apps/8380 or search https://discuss.appium.io

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by this?

"However, we don't know how to move the handle from the browser the app container."

The instant app should launch automatically and take over the screen once its URL has been matched by the browser.

Comment: Instant Apps is launched the same way Deep Links are handled so the approach on Appium is similar. See these for help: https://discuss.appium.io/t/clicking-on-an-intent-url-non-http-link-inside-a-webview-solved/5022, https://discuss.appium.io/t/deep-linking-with-appium/3365, https://discuss.appium.io/t/deeplinking-scheme-url-testing-on-android/4163

Comment: @Deep, i hope your problems has been solve. can you get back if you have   same problems.

Answer (score 0):

Instant Apps is launched the same way Deep Links are handled so the approach on Appium is similar. See these for help

[***Help***](https://discuss.appium.io/t/deeplinking-scheme-url-testing-on-android/4163)